# .mov file is not supported in my laravel blade file with <video> HTML

Tags: laravel-5, html5-video

I am trying to display .mov video on my laravel blade file,but i cannot get visualization of video getting only audio from the file.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head> <title> Video </title>
</head>

<body>
 <video width="400" controls autoplay>
    <source src="sample_iTunes.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if your .mov a correctly encoded mp4 for html5 playback?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal can you tell where is the issue in above code?

Comment: code is fine, my guess is your .mov needs transcoding to comply with supported HTML5 video requirements